# How to set up SolrNet as add-on to Internet Explorer

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am trying to get the same search bar functionality that is present in Solr Velocity as an add-on to Internet Explorer. Is SolrNet the correct way to go? I have no idea about SolrNet, so how can I set it up to make a web app for my data in Solr? I have downloaded the SolrNet source code and I ran runsample.bat successfully, but how do I modify the code to suit my needs?

Comment: http://www.opensearch.org/

Comment: @MauricioScheffer I need the add-on search bar on my browser to have auto-suggest and spell check just like the Solr Velocity search bar. Will opensearch do that as well?

Comment: Also is it open source? I need the technology I use to be open source

Comment: http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/Extensions/Suggestions

Comment: Browse around opensearch.org for more details.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer I have been going through the documentation, but I do not know how to integrate Open Search with Solr. Do you have any references?

Comment: Just write the code to provide the endpoints that opensearch needs, there's not much to it.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer I tried creating the opensearch description file, and created a HTML file with a link on click of which I invoke window.external.AddSearchProvider and give the path of the XML. But on starting this HTML in IE8, I get an ActiveX pop up and after allowing it I get the error: The search provider could not be installed

This might have happened because-:

- A required file could not be downloaded

- The website is unavailable

- You are not connected to the internet

You may want to try again later. Do you know what the problem could be? How can I resolve this?

Comment: @MauricioScheffer Also I was able to create the XML using enhanceie.com and create a search provider but this does not allow me to add suggestions and icons, hence I am trying the other approach.

Comment: You need to write the *server-side* code that implements opensearch endpoints.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer Thank you so much for your help. I was able to add the provider on the browser. But the suggestions are not working. I suppose opensearch needs the JSON to have all suggestions in an array, but that is not how Solr returns it. How can I achieve that?